# Calculate standard deviation only on values between x and y

Tags: excel, stdev

i have a range of data in column a called mycol. Some values are clearly errors (ie, less than 0 or over 100000. If I don't omit those values the stdev is highly skewed. Therefore I want to calculate the stdev only on the values >0 and < 100000. Can you please explain the best way to do this?

I thought about creating a named range consisting of only those within the limits, but I'm not sure if named ranges are dynamic in that way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math question and off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

With array formulas this is pretty straight forward.

*Note Array Formulas are entered with:* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Use an `IF` statement with the references to factor out the values you don't want to include i.e. `>0 and < 100000` and then just surround it with the proper `STDEV` formula.  Here is an example with `STDEV.S` and using the range `A1:A5`

```
=STDEV.S(IF(((A1:A5>0)*(A1:A5<100000)=1),A1:A5))
```

If you have `mycol` as a named range:

```
=STDEV.S(IF(((mycol>0)*(mycol<100000)=1),mycol))
```

Comment: Thanks so much @chancea. That did the trick. What is the "*" and the "=1" doing? Is that because true evaluates to 1 for both of them, so 1*1 = 1?

Comment: @JeffJohnson Yeah and actually you can remove the `=1` because what you said is completely accurate `1=true` so therefore `IF(1,...)` will work just fine.  I just left it in there for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Order the column in excel by ascending or descending. Then find all values before 0 and delete. Next find all values above say 100 000? delete them. Just a simple way to get rid of the values.    CTRL + F to find 0 in excel once you have filtered by desc or ascending.

Comment: i don't actually want to modify the source data

Comment: Technically the data is still there in a filter-- it's just hiding. Thanks for the verification.